# How to show the following change of variables?

Tags: calculus, analysis, differential-geometry, change-of-variable

I am reading the following preprint: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1010.5821.pdf and my goal is to deduce (A.3) from (A.2) [see page 9].

Given $f\in L^{2^*}(\mathbb{S}^n)$ we define $F\in L^{2^*}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ such that
$$F(x) = J_S^{1/2^*}(x) f(S(x))$$
where $S:\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{S}^n$ such that $S(x)=\left(\frac{2x}{1+|x|^2},\frac{1-|x|^2}{1+|x|^2}\right)$ and the jacobian of the map $J_{S}(x) = \left(\frac{2}{1+|x|^2}\right)^{n}.$  Then I want to show that,
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}|\nabla F|^2 dx = \int_{\mathbb{S}^n} |\nabla f|^2 + \frac{n(n-2)}{4}|f|^2 d\omega.$$

I tried the compute the derivatives using the representation of $F$ but the computations do not seem to simplify.

Comment: Have you tried to use the divergence theorem on the left side of the equation?

Comment: @Elad not sure what you mean, could you please explain it further?

Comment: Maybe try green identity $$\int_{B_r} u \Delta u d V_{g}=\int_{ B_r}\langle\operatorname{grad} u, \operatorname{grad} u\rangle_{g} d V_{g}-\int_{\partial B_r} u N u d V_{\tilde{g}}$$

Comment: $F$ should be $|J_{S}(x)|^{(n-2)/2n}f(S(x))$.